# How to call scheduler from Main Class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cron, scheduler

My application  have two schedulers one runs every day at a particular time and another scheduler every day at and interval of 1 hour.
I have added the cron expression in deploy.Yaml without using the scheduler tag.I am calling the first scheduler from App.java..But now I am confused about the second scheduler how can I call the second scheduler in App.java.I am planning to implement with a switch.can someone help me on this please.What I am trying is to route to the scheduler using Java configuration without using XML Configuration

```
Deploy.yaml`spec: scheduler:* * * * * *`

Public class job2 {Public void job2function() {}`}`}`

Public class job1 { `public void job1fun(){}`}`}`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your 2 components for the scheduler job.

```
@Component    
public class Job1 {
    @Scheduled(cron = "${job1.cron.expression:0 2 1 * * ?}")
    public void running() {
        // implementation
    }
}

@Component    
public class Job2 {
    @Scheduled(cron = "${job2.cron.expression:0 1 1 * * ?}")
    public void running() {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

Spring boot will automatically scheduled the related components as a job to run.

And in the above cron expression,  it can e customized in your deploy.yaml file to specify them.

deploy.yaml:

```
......
applications:
  env:
    job2.cron.expression: '0 2 1 * * ?'
    job1.cron.expression: '0 1 1 * * ?'
.......
```

Please try it.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply.but my cron expression is in deploy.yaml file

Comment: You can use a user-env/property to define the dynamic property value in the
@Scheduled part.

e.g.
`Job2 {`
`@Value("${schedule.interval:60}000")`
`private int interval= 60000;`
`@Scheduled(fixedRateString = "${schedule.interval:60}000")`
In the yaml, you just define the property:  schedule.interval with your defined value.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more on this.

Comment: Just add more details in the answer part. Please check. Hope it can help you.